# Prove that infimum of a metric outer measure is a metric outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact measure space and $\mathcal{O}(X)=\{U\subset X, \textrm{U - open set}\}$
and let $\lambda$: $\mathcal{O}(X) \rightarrow \left[0,+\infty\right]$ be a metric outer measure.
Prove that $\mu^*(A)=\inf_{A\subset B\in\mathcal{O}(X)} \lambda(B)$ is a metric outer measure.

I have just troubles with the last condition:

$A, ~B\in \mathcal{O}(X)~\textrm{and}~\rho(A,B)>0 \Rightarrow \mu^*(A\cup B)=\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)$,

where $\rho(A,B):=\inf{\{d(x,y):~x\in A,~y \in B\}}.$

Do you know how to show it or find any sources containing the proof?

Comment: you can consider the infinum only among the open sets that are positively separated from the other set

Comment: I don't get it, can you explain more?

Comment: Ok, first, i think you wat $\mu^*$ to be defined for all sets, not just open, right? So let $A,B\subset X$ be such that $\rho(A,B)=r>0$. Let $A'=\bigcup_{x\in A} B(x,\frac{r}{3})$ and $B'=\bigcup_{x\in B} B(x,\frac{r}{3})$, which are open and $\rho(A,B)\ge \frac{r}{3}>0$. Then $\mu^*(A)$ can be calculated as infimum of $\lambda(U)$, where $A\subset U\subset A'$, and same for $B$ and $B'$, as well as $A\cup B$ and $A'\cup B'$.

Comment: I understand but I still can't see why the condition is satisfied according to what you have written.

Comment: Okay, never mind. I drew it, thanks for help!